# Composition of Lie Derivatives

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, lie-derivative

I was wondering if anyone has any insight into what the composition of the lie derivative would look like.

For example say you take the lie derivative of some p-form $ \omega $ with $X$ and then $Y$. Using Cartan's formula it looks something like this

$$ \mathcal{L}_Y(\mathcal{L}_X\omega) = (i_Yd+di_Y)(i_Xd\omega+d(i_X\omega))=i_Yd(i_Xd\omega) +di_Yi_Xd\omega +  di_Yd(i_X\omega)$$

I was wondering if there are some simplifications that can be made that could get it into a familiar form.

Comment: I am not sure what kind of "familiar form" you would hope for. The composition $\mathcal L_Y\circ\mathcal L_X$ is a second order differential operator on a general manifold (without a Riemannian metric), so it is hard to imagine what kind of "familiar" stuff could be used to describe it ...

Comment: What if there was a Riemannian metric, or some other metric for that matter? And basically, I guess I'm asking if there is any simplification for the composition of the inclusion maps with respect to different vector fields. And I suppose by familiar I mean if anyone has seen any investigation into this.

Comment: In presence of a (pseudo-)Riemannian metric or of a torsion free connection, you can express $\mathcal L_Y(\mathcal L_X\omega)$ in terms of $\nabla^2\omega$. The insertions operators associated to the two vector fields anti-commute, but this won't really help. The point is that you really get an expression depending on second derivatives of the components of $\omega$.  The other way to get something familiar is that $\mathcal L_Y\circ \mathcal L_X-\mathcal L_X\circ \mathcal L_Y=\mathcal L_{[XY]}$.